# couldn't read from SerialPort

Tags: c#, serial-port

can anybody check below codes for C#. There is a issue at `float sıcaklık = Convert.ToByte(seriPort.ReadExisting());` But I couldn't find out what is wrong? I guess SerialPort couldn't get the data.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort seriPort;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        seriPort = new SerialPort();
        seriPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();            
        try
        {
            seriPort.PortName = textBox1.Text;
            if (!seriPort.IsOpen)
            MessageBox.Show("Bağlantı Kuruldu");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bağlantı Kurulmadı!");
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            seriPort.Write("temperature");
            float sıcaklık = Convert.ToByte(seriPort.ReadExisting());
            textBox2.Text = sıcaklık.ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception) {}
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        seriPort.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere `seriPort.Open` ? And do you think `if (!seriPort.IsOpen)` is correct (https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Ba%C4%9Flant%C4%B1%20Kuruldu) ?

Comment: You should add what kind of error do you get at that line, so we can help you more easily

Comment: if you swallow the exceptions how can you/we find the reason of the failure?

Comment: ReadExisting() almost surely returns an empty string, it takes time to transmit and receive a response.  You of course cannot convert an empty string to a byte, FormatException is the expected outcome.  You'll have to throw this code away, it is unfit to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. After assigning the `Name` to the port you need to open it so that communication can take place:

```
seriPort.PortName = textBox1.Text;
// open the port
seriPort.Open();
```

Second thing is, that communication needs **time** to take place. Imagine you talk to someone. You ask him for the current `temperature`. Then you have to wait until your partner has spoken until the end. Only then you will have your desired information, which you can use.
Since you stick here to a synchronous approach you have to give the device as much time as it needs to answer. You could just wait:

```
seriPort.Write("temperature");
// wait for the response
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
float sıcaklık = Convert.ToByte(seriPort.ReadExisting());
```

I would not really recommend this synchronous approach, but rather use the `DataReceived`. It will be fired when your device sends you data und you have received it.

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;

private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    float sıcaklık = Convert.ToByte(seriPort.ReadExisting());
    // do what ever you want with this value
}
```

Hope that helps